# In what way does meat cooked in a stew differ from marinaded grilled foods in terms of flavour absorption by meat?

Tags: marinade, stews

When you eat a curry which has been cooked on the stove it seems the meat has flavour but it is still very different from something which has been marinaded and grilled.

I guess a curry doesn't have a marinade but it sits in a pot of curry powder\sauce so that's where the meat gets its flavour from.

To what extent do the sauces penetrate the meats cooked in the different ways and how does the cooking method cause this?

Even if there is no penetration and its only surface treatment, I'd still like to know why both methods taste so different even though both have surface treatment.

Comment: Marination is a surface treatment.  The flavor doesn't penetrate.

Comment: @moscafj I've read statements that suggest some types of marinade do 'penetrate deeper' but not sure of the facts hence asking.  Even if its just penetrates the surface by very little, i'd still like to know how it differs from a curry\stew.

Comment: Many variables....for starters, probably different cuts of meat...different fat/connective tissue content...one is cooked in a "sauce", one is not...might not have anything to do with marinade. Point being, meat probably doesn't "absorb" flavor.